# SignalR 2.2.0 How to get mroe details. Error Value cannot be null Parameter S

Tags: signalr, .net-4.5, signalr.client

From time to time we have the following error in our log.

We are using LongPolling with SignalR.

I Created a logging middleware but I currently don't get more informationos then you can see below.

I found some posts about this error but most things were spongily.

We have high traffic on the site but only one per hour creates this error.

Currently we open the connection when the site is called and close it when the user leaves the site.

So I tried what happens when I close the windows while returning data but this doesn't create this error.

So I currently search any hint about this error and how to get more informations, about exact query string, browser and so on..

Any advice?

> Unexpected exception: /send.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: s
 at System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JsonSerializerExtensions.Parse[T](JsonSerializer serializer, String json)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubRequestParser.Parse(String data, JsonSerializer serializer)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReceived(IRequest request, String connectionId, String data)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.<>c__DisplayClassa.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ProcessRequestPostGroupRead>b__7()
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Func`1 func)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.LongPollingTransport.<ProcessSendRequest>d__16.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
 at GP.Hosting.HostingLogMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext() in D:\GreenParrot\src\GP.Hosting\GP.Hosting\HostingLogMiddleware.cs:line 82
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your exception matches this issue for SignalR 2.2.0 
Check the details in this issue thread:

- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3374

I'm experiencing the same.

Some have diagnosed this trigger by SignalR being challenged by NTLM.
Others have had URL rewriting rules that trigger this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove Logging Middleware Extensions and then try sending messages. For me it worked fine. Somehow Middleware Extensions failed sending messages.